# What is the best practice naming convention for a Django project?

Tags: django

Should the project name be the same as the site name? Or should be be called something else like "django," "settings," "project-settings" or something else?

I know it doesn't really matter in the end, but I'm curious what the best practice is or what you prefer to name you Django projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, my project name is confusing with apps name.

I choose this naming:

```
foo_project/
  manage.py
  main/ # project name, contains settings
  apps/ # contains all my apps `from apps.foos.models import ...`
    foos/
    other_stuff/
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to name it **according to the main goal of your app**. For example, one that will deal with the users can be named registration (it's a real app name).

Naming the apps according to what they do, not only makes the project more scalable, but also avoid confusion between the project name and apps.

If there is only one or two apps, naming it like the project is OK, though. Same if it's the core of your project and the other apps will be only secondary (I still don't recommend it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I was mis-understanding how projects were created when I asked my question. I thought a project was a new folder created inside the root directory of my site folder. But it looks like I need to create a project and that project folder becomes the root of my site.

So if my site was mysite.com, I could call my project mysite. Django would then create a mysite folder (the root of my site), and inside that folder would be another folder called mysite which contains the Django settings.

Each app would then be in the root mysite folder with your naming convention.

Comment: The question is about the project name, not app names.

Answer (score 0):

I call it `__project__`, so that I can easily distinguish its folder from the rest of the apps.